# How to set manualy color of params[] and redirect_to in Vim?

Tags: vim, syntax, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

This is my colorscheme -> https://gist.github.com/1973544

[image: This is my vim window]

But in example screenshot of sexy-railscasts: https://github.com/oguzbilgic/sexy-railscasts-theme

[image: sexy-railscasts]

`params[]` and `redirect_to` are colored.

How to achieve this?

EDIT: Problem is with filetypes. Releated -> [Ultisnips break rails syntax. How to setup correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557643/ultisnips-break-rails-syntax-how-to-setup-correctly#comment12118102_9557643)

Comment: I am not a ruby programmer but I think the problem is NOT with the color schemes you are using! In fact both the color schemes you've mentioned are not working as you expected on my gVim! The think the problem here is with the `ruby.vim` language syntax file which is not able to figure out that `redirect_to` is a function/method/procedure call. The person who posted the screenshot might be using some different ruby language syntax file than yours and hence its highlighted for him!

Comment: While we figure out the changes needed in ruby.vim to make this work, why don't you can ask the developer himself ;-) https://github.com/oguzbilgic

Comment: Yes. But I realize what could be wrong. My ```filetype``` is  ```ruby.rails``` and when i cheange it to ```set  filetype=ruby``` syntax works. But then my ultisnips dont recognize rails snippets, how to compare this two things??

Comment: Simple: choose what is the most important for you. For me, code completion is a thousand times more important than syntax coloring. If you can't decide, you'll have to get in touch with tpope **and** sirver to see if/how this incompatibility problem between their two plugins can be fixed.

Comment: Please see my comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557643/ultisnips-break-rails-syntax-how-to-setup-correctly/9583824#9583824

Comment: Tim and I have worked out a solution. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557643/ultisnips-break-rails-syntax-how-to-setup-correctly/9583824 to get your cake and eat it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This colorscheme is, as specified in its header, "A GUI Only port of the RailsCasts TextMate theme to Vim.".

GUI colorschemes (for GVim or MacVim) can make use of thousands of colors. If you want to make Vim look like in the official screenshot you'll need to use GVim.

But you appear to be using it in a terminal emulator which can only display a maximum of 256 colors. For this "GUI Only" colorscheme to even work in your terminal, you probably have a color conversion plugin like CSApprox, do you? Such plugins will do their best to match your GUI colors to their closest equivalent in the [X11 set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) but this task is *obviously **not*** foolproof. Some colors may be frankly off and I'm almost certain that's what's happening here.

*EDIT*

First, I don't do Ruby, even on Rails.

Second, the syntax group of `params` in `params[:comment]` depends on the filetype:

- if I have `:set ft=ruby.rails`:

  ```
  rubyBlock, rubyMethodBlock, rubyLocalVariableOrMethod
  ```
- if I have `:set ft=ruby`:

  ```
  rubyBlock, rubyMethodBlock, rubyRailsMethod
  ```

The problem is that `rubyLocalVariableOrMethod`, as defined in the default ruby syntax file appears to not being linked to `Function` unlike `rubyRailsMethod`, from the rails plugin.

So I think that it's the `rubyLocalVariableOrMethod` that is causing problems. I've been looking around on my machine and can't seem to find how, why and by whom it is set instead of `rubyRailsMethod` when `ft=ruby.rails`.

While waiting for a real solution, there is a global setting for using rails completion when `:set ft=ruby`, I think it should help: `let g:rubycomplete_rails = 1`.

Comment: No. gVim is not the solution. I tried loading his color schemes in my gVim but the problem still persists! In fact in both color schemes he has mentioned!

Comment: But I still don't know how to make it work. I know the problem but not the solution (yet!) :(

Comment: Well, I think David Brown is right. Rails.vim adds a bunch of keywords to ruby's default syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that is from the [rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) plugin.