# Ultisnips break rails syntax. How to setup correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, syntax

https://github.com/sirver/ultisnips <- Edited

Im using ultisnips and my rails snippets works only when i have `ruby.rails` filetype.

`:set filetype=ruby.rails`

But then i dont have rails syntax. Because syntax works on `:set filetype=ruby`

How to setup filetype or recognize syntax correctly?

EDIT:
Reported to ultisnips launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ultisnips/+bug/946549

Comment: That repo is unmaintained, does it work if you use the [SirVer/ultisnips](https://github.com/sirver/ultisnips) repo?

Comment: Ok, I change repo but i have the same issue. Sirver says that is not ultisnips bug.

Comment: Releated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556230/how-to-set-manualy-color-of-params-and-redirect-to-in-vim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some trouble understanding the problem. If you want rails snippet in ruby file type, why don't you just create a file `~/.vim/UltiSnips/ruby.snippets` and add a line

```
extends rails
```

Or is your trouble setting the filetype to ruby.rails? If so, make a new file ~/.vim/ftdetect/rails.vim (name doesn't matter).

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.rails set ft=ruby.rails
```

Quick edit: There is now also UltiSnipsAddFiletypes (not yet in 2.1, will be in 2.2 and it is already in the repository). You can also edit ~/.vim/ftplugin/rails.vim and add

```
UltiSnipsAddFiletypes rails.ruby
```

Comment: Does UltiSnips work out of the box with simple files, or am I supposed to add an `autocmd` for each? Because I'm trying to use the `def` snippet in a `.py` file and it only works after I do `:UltiSnipsAddFiletypes python`, although in the status bar, vim says it's a python file.

Comment: UltiSnips works out of the box. Just make sure your plugin manager adds ftdetect to your runtimepath (vundle and pathogen do that).

Comment: `echo &runtimepath` contains `/home/flav/.vim/bundle/ultisnips` and `/home/flav/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/after`. I have installed the bundle from `Bundle 'SirVer/ultisnips'` (that is, from github).

Comment: I have added `autocmd FileType * call UltiSnips_FileTypeChanged()` and it started to work as expected.

Comment: As mentioned, you should not need the autocommand. Instead your bundle manager should add ftdetect to vims search path. If it does not do that you should file a bug. Also see https://github.com/gmarik/vundle/issues/16 . Nonproper usage of Vundle affects UltiSnips as well.

Comment: I have set it exactly like the manual and that bug report says, yes, but it does not work without the `autocmd`

Comment: If that is the case, you should strip down your vim config to a bare minimum that reproduces this and file a bug with the config attached. It is very likely that you will find that some other plugin is misbehaving and resetting autocommands or therelike in the process.